# How to make custom UIComponent Accessible?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, accessibility, testcomplete

I added a MXML component in flex and selected the base as UIComponent. I want to make it accessible so that automated testing tools can Access it. I am using TestComplete for automated testing. As TestComplete uses Microsoft Accessibility classes. Now it treat my component as the Graphics.

How Can I do this??

Comment: What TestComplete version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have much luck automating Flex using MSAA, because the object hierarchy and information reported by MSAA is very limited. To improve things, you could try [compiling your application with accessibility enabled](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7da1.html) and also [creating a custom accessibility implementation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSaa0aa854ca84f61622f85eff1221e9fba3a-8000.html) for your component. However, I doubt it will make much difference.

Having said that, you should really consider upgrading to the TestComplete 8.20, because this version has proper support for Flex. By "proper" I mean that it identifies all objects inside Flex applications (including custom components), provides extra test objects for automating Flex controls and also lets you automate controls using their native properties. In addition, this version can dynamically load the testing library into Flex applications, so that no changes to the application's source code or build process are required.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the official documentation about [Creating Applications for Testing](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/functest_components2_01.html)

Especially the part about [instrumenting custom components](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/functest_components2_13.html#205337)

Answer (score 0):

It should work, if the application was correctly prepared for testing with TestComplete. Check the [Preparing Flex Applications for Testing with Automation APIs](http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/19971/) topic to learn more.